# Python getting weird HTTP errors

Tags: python

The usage of the code is to get the HTTP titles of the URLLIST provided.

Am getting the following error in some hosts, also after it finishes, i have to force close the program to exit. Please help me solve these issues.
I am getting the error below

httperror_seek_wrapper: HTTP Error 404: /

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import urllib
import workerpool
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from mechanize import Browser
import sys

def titleprint(url):
    br = Browser()
    br.set_handle_robots(False)
    res = br.open(url, None, 2.5)
    data = res.get_data()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
    title = soup.find('title')
    if soup.title != None:
        print url, title.renderContents(), '\n'
# Initialize a pool, 5 threads in this case
pool = workerpool.WorkerPool(size=5)

# The ``Title Print`` method will be called with a line from the second
# parameter for each job.
pool.map(titleprint, open("urls.txt").readlines())

# Send shutdown jobs to all threads, and wait until all the jobs have been completed
pool.shutdown()
    pool.wait()
```

Comment: workerpool module is downloaded from https://github.com/shazow/workerpool

Comment: If it does not work in multithreaded environment, you could try in single threaded one and say whether if solves the problem or not. But it would be simpler to test...

Comment: `readlines()` doesn't strip newline characters from the end of the lines, so those will be part of the download url. chances are good that some sites will return a 404...

Comment: @mata how can i properly set exceptions for the error ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta the script works fine in multi-threaded, but i want to know how i can fix the exceptions.

Comment: Is it a true exception and to you have any stacktrace ?

Comment: `Exception in thread Thread-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 203, in open
    return self._mech_open(url, data, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 255, in _mech_open
    raise response
httperror_seek_wrapper: HTTP Error 404: /`

Comment: if the script hits a host which is down, this is the msg i get. ? but it continues to the next one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue, i was using urllib not urllib2, anyways the correct code is below, but i couldn't fix the SIGINT (CTRL+C) break. :(

```
import os
import urllib2
import socket
import workerpool
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from mechanize import Browser
import signal
import time
import sys

def titleprint(url):
    try:
        br = Browser()
        br.set_handle_robots(False)
        res = br.open(url, None, 2.5)
        data = res.get_data()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
        title = soup.find('title')
        if soup.title != None:
                print url, title.renderContents(), '\n'
        else:
                print "No Title Found"
    except urllib2.URLError, e:
        print url,"Oops, timed out?", '\n'
    except socket.error,e:
        print url,"Oops, timed out?", '\n'
    except socket.timeout:
        print url,"Oops, timed out?", '\n'


def signal_handler(signal, frame):
        print('You pressed Ctrl+C!')
        sys.exit(0)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
pool = workerpool.WorkerPool(size=20)
pool.map(titleprint, open("urls.txt").readlines())
pool.shutdown()
pool.wait()
print 'Processing of list completed, Cheers!!'
sys.exit(1)
print('Stop the script using Ctrl+C')
signal.pause()
```

Comment: if anyone can find out the issue with SIGINT, please enlighten me :(

Comment: why do you have an infinite loop there?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid am a noob at coding, am ripping off codes and trying to achieve this, could you point where i have gone wrong ? infinite loop where ?